# Can't run Android OpenCV face detection example

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, opencv, android-ndk

I'm trying to compile and run the OpenCV face detection example but it won't let me. I'm using Linux Mint 17, Eclipse with ADT and NDK installed. I have the gcc, g++, build-essentials packages installed. I'm getting the following errors:

[image: errors]

[image: includes]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should compile that stuff for *ARM* architecture (depending on your device). In principle **gcc** can do that but it is a little bit of work because your need **android ndk**, **android sdk** and **android built-tools**.

I advice you to start very simple. Having a running empty app that calls a native c++ function. And once this is settled your should proceed to opencv.

Have a look at this. I made it https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line

Comment: @masm64: As of now, your question is too vague, and there could be too many possible solutions. Armen is very right here; you should start with running the complete code on your laptop/desktop. Then, run a small piece of OpenCV code like capturing camera video on Android. What you are going through is simply the setup problems and doing it correctly will save a lot of time in future as you will be aware of the intricacies of how OpenCV(or other native libraries) should be integrated into your application.

Comment: a simple "hello world" application is working, but as soon as I try to do something more complex like this it just won't work and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong